# Javascript Foreach only reads 1 line

Tags: javascript

When I am trying to get the SpeechModule to display the foreach loop, The Text to speech only reads the first part and then stops.

```
function SpeechModule(var1)
{
   const TxtToSpeech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let search = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;

    TxtToSpeech.text = search;
   
    TxtToSpeech.volume = 2;
    TxtToSpeech.rate = 0.5;
    TxtToSpeech.pitch = 2;
   
    TxtToSpeech.voice = voices[4];
   
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(TxtToSpeech);

}
```

```
    <?php foreach($JSON as $file): ?>
    
   <div id="data">
      
    <p> <?php echo $display->firstname; ?> </p>
    <p> <?php echo $display->lastname; ?> </p>    
</div>    
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$index=1;

foreach($JSON as $file): ?>
    
<div id="text<?php echo $index; ?>">
      
    <h1> Title: <?php echo $display->title; ?> </h1>
    <h2> First Name: <?php echo $display->firstname; ?> </h2>    
</div>    
    
    <?php 
$index++;

endforeach; ?>



function TextToSpeech(var1)
{
   const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let convert = document.getElementById("text" + var1).innerHTML;

    speech.text = convert;
   
    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;
   
    speech.voice = voices[1];
   
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);

}
```

After the above amendments , please write a program to run the  TextToSpeech(1), TextToSpeech(2), TextToSpeech(3) sequentially. (you can use loop from 1 to $index).

Answer (score 0):

From your codes , I believe the div id (named "text") will appear more than once.

If this is the case, the system will then not be able to distinguish which div you are referring in your TextToSpeech function (or if it can, it will only process the first one)

Comment: That makes sense but, Is there a way for the "text" function to read all of the foreach loop?